# Align BUT with large math text?

Tags: align, tex-core

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\hbadness=99999
\hfuzz=9999pt



\title{Week 2 Question}
\author{}
\date{October 2020}





\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Question:}


% Prove that $T(x, y)=\frac{x \cdot y}{x+y-x \cdot y}$ is a t-norm, and provide the expression of its dual t-conorm $S(x, y)=1-T(1-x, 1-y)$





 \[
    \mathlarger{\textrm{Prove that } T(x, y)=\frac{x \cdot y}{x+y-x \cdot y} \textrm{ is a t-norm, and provide the expression }}
 \]   

 \[   
    \mathlarger{\textrm{ of its dual t-conorm } S(x, y)=1-T(1-x, 1-y)}
 \] 


\section*{Answer:}


% Neutral element, Commutativity, Monotonicity and Associativity

% Upside down A means "for all"

% I am trying to solve a tnorm equation, but I can't find a simple / for dummies explanation anywhere online and the way I have been explained it, in class makes no sense to me, therefore I am stuck, I don't expect you to answer the following question but I really really need some advice of where I even begin to solve it: https://i.gyazo.com/98b4f79cde3767b397af6d043e1b2952.png I know I need, Neutral element, Commutativity, Monotonicity and Associativity but I just do not know where to even start, the explanations everywhere seem so bad I don't understand at all, please help.


\subsection*{Neutral/Identity element:}



\subsection*{Commutativity:}

\subsection*{Monotonicity:}

\subsection*{Associativity:}




\section*{References:}
\begin{sloppypar}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Gupta, M.M. and Qi, J. (1991) Theory of T-norms and fuzzy inference methods. Fuzzy Sets and Systems, 40(3), pp. 431–450.
  \item Lecture 2 - Lecture slides (Slides 36 to 50)
  \item Mathworks Additional Fuzzy Operators. Available from: \url{https://uk.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/foundations-of-fuzzy-logic.html\#bp78l70-6} [Accessed 17/10/20].
\end{enumerate}
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```

For the above code, lines 34 to 40 inclusive, where the two elements are in math mode, I keep trying to alighn especially the second formula to the left of the page but in math mode it won't let me do it and if I use $ to indicate its math in latex instead of math mode then I can't use \mathlarger, so what would be a good solution here so I can keep text large but left align?

Comment: equations are centred by default if you want them flush left add `[fleqn]` option to `\documentclass` if you want the entire display large just put `\large` before the display, no need for a package or `\mathlarger`

Comment: what do you mean by put \large before the display?

Comment: `\Large \[x=y\]`

Comment: why have you got `\hfuzz=9999pt` ??? That means tex will allow things to stick 4 metres off the page without warning you????

Comment: I just don't like the warnings ok lol

Comment: There is no reason to have warnings, but most people would avoid the warnings by keeping the text on the page rather than asking not to be warned if the text is off the page and invisible/

Comment: Many thanks overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what layout you want put perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% not needed in current latex \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% not needed here\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}


% only if you don't want tex to try to make good output \hbadness=99999
% only if you don't mind over-large items sticking 4 metres off the page \hfuzz=9999pt



\title{Week 2 Question}
\author{}
\date{October 2020}





\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Question:}


% Prove that $T(x, y)=\frac{x \cdot y}{x+y-x \cdot y}$ is a t-norm, and provide the expression of its dual t-conorm $S(x, y)=1-T(1-x, 1-y)$




\Large
 Prove that $ T(x, y)=\frac{x \cdot y}{x+y-x \cdot y}$  is a t-norm, and provide the expression   
 of its dual $t$-conorm $S(x, y)=1-T(1-x, 1-y)$
 
\normalsize

\section*{Answer:}


% Neutral element, Commutativity, Monotonicity and Associativity

% Upside down A means "for all"

% I am trying to solve a tnorm equation, but I can't find a simple / for dummies explanation anywhere online and the way I have been explained it, in class makes no sense to me, therefore I am stuck, I don't expect you to answer the following question but I really really need some advice of where I even begin to solve it: https://i.gyazo.com/98b4f79cde3767b397af6d043e1b2952.png I know I need, Neutral element, Commutativity, Monotonicity and Associativity but I just do not know where to even start, the explanations everywhere seem so bad I don't understand at all, please help.


\subsection*{Neutral/Identity element:}



\subsection*{Commutativity:}

\subsection*{Monotonicity:}

\subsection*{Associativity:}




\section*{References:}
\raggedright
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Gupta, M.M. and Qi, J. (1991) Theory of T-norms and fuzzy inference methods. Fuzzy Sets and Systems, 40(3), pp. 431–450.
  \item Lecture 2 - Lecture slides (Slides 36 to 50)
  \item Mathworks Additional Fuzzy Operators. Available from: \url{https://uk.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/foundations-of-fuzzy-logic.html\#bp78l70-6} [Accessed 17/10/20].
\end{enumerate}


\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. :-) I would also load the `xurl` package, to improve the way the long URL gets typeset.

Comment: @Mico I wondered about that, but didn't want to cloud the main message which is "don't load stuff you don't need, that breaks your document" the details of the formatting of the example could be improved in several places (I probably would avoid the line break in the inline math here as well.)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the font size and the best thing to do is to define a specific environment:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newenvironment{question}
 {\section*{Question:}\Large}
 {\par}

\title{Week 2 Question}
\author{}
\date{October 2020}





\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{question}
Prove that $T(x, y)=\frac{xy}{x+y-xy}$ is a t-norm, and 
provide the expression of its dual t-conorm $S(x, y)=1-T(1-x, 1-y)$.
\end{question}

\section*{Answer:}

Something to answer the question.

\end{document}
```

Here I used `\Large` to magnify the effect. Use `\large` if you prefer, but I'd simply stay with normal size, because the header already gives the required prominence.

I added `geometry` to get a wider text block, but it's not required.

[image]